# "For always" meaning "forever"

Tags: phrases, phrase-usage

I have occasionally heard "for always" used to mean "forever". This is a random example from Google Books:

> “Of course,” she said. “And I love you. For always.”

COCA returns hundreds of hits for "for always", mostly false positives though. And "love you for always" narrows it down to three hits. [Google searches](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS910US910&sxsrf=ALeKk03DZCUqhroK2NW7lWhfa0KvC0XxLg%3A1604708421728&ei=ReilX-KELPGs0PEP5s6boAY&q=%22for%20always%22%20forever&oq=%22for%20always%22%20forever&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzIICC4QyQMQkwIyAgguMgIIADICCAAyAggAMgYIABAWEB4yBggAEBYQHjIGCAAQFhAeMgYIABAWEB4yBggAEBYQHjoECAAQRzoECCMQJzoFCC4QyQM6CAguEMcBEK8BUI8eWO0lYKQnaABwAngAgAHMAYgBpgaSAQU2LjEuMZgBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXrIAQjAAQE&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwiiu8fblO_sAhVxFjQIHWbnBmQQ4dUDCA0&uact=5) indicate this turn of phrase has been invoked in [songs](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22for%20always%22&sxsrf=ALeKk019e7eTcF32sjYXUOlQLqqGhJE4mw:1604709150123&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjylfG2l-_sAhWUFTQIHYTQBHAQ_AUICigA&biw=3840&bih=2049&dpr=1) fairly commonly. But it apparently doesn't occur in colloquial language very often, so I wonder if it is dialectal and where it originally came from.

Comment: In most cases I would think "for always" has been translated literally from another language.

Comment: The surge in usage after about 1980 [Google 2grams; a bare 'for always'] is probably largely generated by the use of the expression in various predictable genres (Joan Walsh Anglund: 'A is for Always' (!!);1968 // Terry Lynne Graham:  'Fingerplays and Rhymes For Always and Sometimes'; 1984 // Linda Walvoord:  'Adoption is for Always': 1986 // and more recently Janae Mitchell: The For Always Series //  Sophie Love: 'Forever and For Always'; both 2010s)

Comment: ... Link:  [[Google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=for+always&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cfor%20always%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cfor%20always%3B%2Cc1)]

Answer (score 1):

"For always" is relatively common in British English. It is informal and "always" is treated as a synonym of the noun "eternity". There are examples within the [British National Corpus](https://www.english-corpora.org/bnc/):

*'s right, my dear. He's in heaven now. Quite safe for always. Better than being sad and sick.'' He weren't sad,*

*Or shall I go down in history as the High Queen who lost Tara for always?*

*From morn till night. Birth till death. For always and ever. Unwelcome tears of frustration filled her eyes.*

etc.